# Getting error "Avoid second fetch in jenkins git plugin"

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm getting error while running jenkins pipeline "Avoid second fetch"
I have tried few solutions like shallow clone, no-tags but no luck.

My pipeline is like below:

```
Library(@my-lib)_

PipelineCustom{
 branch = "branch"
 mailer = "abc@xyz.com"
}
```

shared lib, jenkins file and code is in same repo.

Is there any way to resolve this issue or i need to keep shared lib in seperate repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Shared libraries disigened for separated repo.

You may add class or function from groovy file with **load** step without double fetch:

```java
my_module = load 'path/to/file/in/repo.groovy'
my_module.myCoolClass()
```

You can try to checkout to subdir behavior. But i'm not shure